# Using an IN statement in the THEN of a CASE

Tags: sql-server, case, sql-in

When I try to use the below line I get this: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'."

```
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN @CostCentreID IS NOT NULL THEN CI.CostCentreID IN(SELECT CAST(Item AS INTEGER) FROM dbo.SplitString(@CostCentreID, ','))
    END
```

I can not figure out what is wrong.

The THEN command works fine outside of the CASE Statement. I am trying to capture the NULL entry. If NULL to completly skip the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your WHERE clause something like.....

```
WHERE @CostCentreID IS NULL 
  OR  CI.CostCentreID IN (
                           SELECT CAST(Item AS INTEGER) 
                           FROM dbo.SplitString(@CostCentreID, ',')
                         )
```